# Voip over Isabella vm

Tags: networking, server, vmware, voip, esxi

In a working VoIP setup i want to replace the PC(Isabella) with new virtual machine(Isabella ready) on a new server(connected to new switch) using  esxi 7

PC is connected to a router right now.
There is a few vm on the server and i think it is better to have a separate network on esxi for voip.

My difficulty is how to connect router to server and network setup.
Shall I connect router to server directly or to the physical switch?

I have to define a new vswitch for this?
How should be the esxi network config?

Any help and guide or address appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think StackOverflow is the right place for this.

Comment: I am googling this for two day ,please pencil me if you know any link for right place to learn this?

Comment: Try posting this on  https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint in this question.
You need to understand the basics about physical world and virtual world.

You have to connect router > switch > server (esxi). It's recommend that use two physical nic on ESXI servers. For performance and security use VLANs for different traffic, you should configure this options on router and switch (l2 administrable switch). Check if your hardware has this options.

At virtual world, you'll have vswitch0 that map your physical nic. Inside this switch you would create your network stack. You don't need to create separate switch for every nic, also It's not recommend, use at least two nic for each vswitch.

VMkernels will handle esxi management like DCUI, vmotion, vsan, iscsi, HA and FT. Port Groups will handle VLAN Traffic for your VMs. So, at this point you should create a separate VLAN for your VOIP VM.

Please check VMware documentation for more details. Hope this comment help you understand basics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so glad someone helped. here what i realized by now:first to join Cisco and network courses, but first i am going to config the switch with few trunk ports and divide it in two VLAN , one for VoIP and one for LAN and i will skip a few port in arrangement for upcoming server, switch,… , then will assign the Voip ( Isabella VM) and Automation port groups to VLANs , next will load the Isabella backup to the VM. It seems easy!!  Let me know if i am right by far?

Comment: You are right this is the way, Good luck with your migration!